# How to redirect application's access to another website with such as privoxy?

Tags: url-rewriting, webrequest

There is an application. It usually access to [https://foo.com] to get datas.

eg. [GET https://foo.com/abc.xml]

The server address [foo.com] can't be changed in application's setting file. But It is able to set a proxy server to access internet.

Now I setup my own website [http(s)://bar.com], which exactly provide the same services as [https://foo.com] do.

The question is, How can I redirect application's access from [foo.com] to [bar.com]?

I try to use privoxy to redirect requests, but it didn't work.

settings in privoxy's user.action file:

```
{+redirect{s@foo.com@bar.com@} }
foo.com
```

but got errors:

```
2014-03-28 15:59:22.820 00000d54 Redirect: pcrs command "s@foo.com@bar.com@" changed "https://foo.com/abc.xml" to "https://bar.com/abc.xml" (1 hit).
2014-03-28 15:59:22.828 00000d54 Redirect: New URL is: https://bar.com/abc.xml
2014-03-28 15:59:22.830 00000d54 Crunch: Redirected: https://foo.com/abc.xml
```

Is there any other solutions?